# Can't understand the behaviour of functions with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to figure out the behaviour of "this" keyword in JavaScript. In general I understand how it behaves in different contexts of function calling, but I'm having some trouble when it's part of an arrow function.

I'm using MDN as a source of information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions.
I have grasped the general concept that in the case of arrow functions "this" retains the value corresponding to the context of the function definition, but I started having trouble when playing with the last example in that section.

The example goes like this:

```
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = (() => this);
    return x;
  }
};

var fn = obj.bar();

console.log(fn() === obj); //true
```

As expected, the console returns true. However, and this is my first doubt, i don't understand why it returns false when I compare obj directly with obj.bar(), since I asume that obj.bar() and fn() invoke the same function:

```
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = (() => this);
    return x;
  }
};

console.log(obj.bar() === obj); //false
```

I started playing with the code trying to find further unexpected behaviours, and there are some more doubts. The second one: when I change the type of definition of bar, "this" in the function apparently starts referring to the global object, although I thought the function was being called as a method of obj. ¿Shouldn't the result be the opposite? ¿Is it because now "this" refers to the context of fn?

```
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = function() {
      return this;
    };
    return x;
  }
};

var fn = obj.bar();

console.log(fn() === obj); //false
console.log(fn() === this); //true
```

Third doubt: if I omit fn again and use directly obj.bar() in the comparison, again I find unexpected results. In this case "this" in the function refers neither to the global object nor to obj (I expected the second, since bar() is called as a method of obj).

```
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = function() {
      return this;
    };
    return x;
  }
};

console.log(obj.bar() === obj); //false
console.log(obj.bar() === this); //false
```

When I try to see directly the value returned by obj.bar() I can't get much help from the console:

```
console.log(obj.bar());
//With arrow definition: () => { length:0
//                               name:x }
//With the second definition: f() => { length:0
//                                     name:"bar"
//                                     prototype: bar}
```

I hope someone here can help me understand what's going on, or at least recommend me a more complete resource. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `fn()` = `(obj.bar())()` not `obj.bar()` (you invoke it twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is `obj.bar()` reutrns a function that is assigned to a variable `fn` and then fn is invoked `fn()`

so

```
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = (() => this);
    return x;
  }
};

console.log(obj.bar()() === obj); //should give you true
```

Answer (score 2):

> I asume that obj.bar() and fn() invoke the same function

No, `obj.bar()` returns the function `x`. It's creating a closure.

> "this" in the function apparently starts referring to the global object, although I thought the function was being called as a method of obj

No, `fn` was not called as a method on `obj`, only `bar` was. `fn()` is called as a plain function.

> if I omit fn again and use directly obj.bar() in the comparison, "this" in the function refers neither to the global object nor to obj

No. The `this` in the function is never even evaluated, the function is never called. You only called `bar`, and then compared the returned function against `obj`.

> When I try to see directly the value returned by obj.bar()

…then the console shows you a function object!